# Limite timestamp 19 de janeiro de 2038

Tags: php

Como é possivel resolver esse bug?

```
echo date('c', mktime(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2038));
```

Resultado

```
1970-01-01T00:00:00+00:00
```

Comment: Reporte para o PHP ;)

Comment: Não é bug do php... Isso é a data limite do timestamp

Comment: existe sim: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303972/format-date-whose-timestamp-exceeds-the-int-limit

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[image: http://2038bug.com/]

Esse bug é causado pelo uso de *4bytes signed integer* utilizados para fazer  contas rápidas.

**O problema:**

[image: efeito do bug]

**Não existe** nenhuma solução universal para o problema do ano 2038, qualquer
mudança na definição do `time_t` pode resultar em problemas de compatibilidade 
em qualquer aplicação

Por exemplo, alterar time_t para um inteiro de 32 bits não assinado, o que estenderia o intervalo para o ano 2106, afetaria negativamente os programas que armazenam, recuperar ou manipular datas antes de 1970, uma vez que tais datas são representados por números negativos. O aumento do tamanho do tipo `time_t` de 64 bits em um sistema existente iria causar alterações incompatíveis para a disposição das estruturas de interface e o binário de funções.

[Wikipedia - Solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem#Solutions)

Answer (score 7):

Apenas para complementar a resposta, quero reletar que com a classe `DateTime` não tive esse problema.

Veja:

```
$date = new DateTime('+1000 years')

echo $date->format('c'); // 3015-11-25T09:20:54-02:00
```

Testado na linha de comando com `psysh`.

**Atualização**: No `ideone.com`, somente a forma destacada no meu exemplo funciona. A forma utilizando a função `date` falha.

http://ideone.com/VoYyOo

**Observação**: Tudo isso funcionará perfeitamente com `DateTime`, a não ser que você use `DateTime::getTimestamp`.

## Testes

Uma boa maneira de testar essas limitações pode ser feita através da constantes `PHP_INT_MAX`, que provavelmente pode ser mudada em diferentes versões do PHP.

Teste 1 `psysh`, PHP 5.5.9 Ubuntu:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimestamp(PHP_INT_MAX);
var_dump($date->format('c')); // 219250468-12-04T13:30:07-02:00
var_dump(PHP_INT_MAX); // int(9223372036854775807)
```

Teste 2 [`ideone.com`](http://ideone.com/FJxcLU):

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimestamp(PHP_INT_MAX);
var_dump($date->format('c')); // 2038-01-19T03:14:07+00:00

var_dump(PHP_INT_MAX); // int(2147483647)
```

Veja que nos dois casos, resultados diferentes foram retornados. Então também posso supor que, por conta do tamanho máximo do integer processado no PHP, isso possa afetar o comportamento das funções.

Comment: +1 Aqui funcionou legal também. essa DateTime  usa 64bits? não sei como ela faz essa magia.

Comment: Não sei @GabrielRodrigues. Mas dê uma olhada nisso que encontrei http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319710/accessing-dates-in-php-beyond-2038

Comment: Atualizei a resposta @GabrielRodrigues. Veja a importante informação do `PHP_INT_MAX`

Comment: Nesse post fala que "O DateTime representa internamente os componentes de tempo de forma independente. Assim, não é suscetível à limitação de 2038." mas não tem nada na documentação do php e não achei nada em outros artigos, o.O

Answer (score 3):

Use os métodos da classe [`\DateTime`](http://php.net/DateTime). Dessa forma, as datas geradas por sua aplicação não são limitadas pela arquitetura que o PHP está rodando (no caso, 32 bits).

Comment: Bom saber dessa informação, Rodrigo. Mais um motivo para usar o Objeto, ao invés da Função