# A função para pegar o dia da semana do PHP tem limite?

Tags: php, data

Estou fazendo um calendário utilizando o PHP e JS e funcionou perfeitamente entre o ano de 1902 até 2037, pois a partir de 2038 a função para pegar o dia da semana no PHP retorna um valor incorreto. Existe algum motivo específico para isto?

Segue o código utilizado na primeira imagem até onde ainda funciona e na segunda imagem onde começa a pegar o valor incorreto.

Na imagem onde tem a divisória "|" do lado esquerdo é o dia da semana do mês e do lado direito o retorno da função abaixo.

```
function getDayWeek($date){
    return date("w", strtotime($date));
}
```

[image: Calendário até o mês que roda normalmente]

[image: Calendário a partir do mês que código retorna valor incorreto]

Comment: Relacionada: [Limite timestamp 19 de janeiro de 2038](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100231/91) e [Limite para a função strtotime em php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/109985/91)

Comment: Relacionado: [Problema do Ano 2038](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/378936/112052)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sim, tem, é chamado *bug* do milênio II ou *bug* do *timestamp* do Unix ou [Y2K38 Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem). Isto ocorre porque o Unix determinou que o horário começaria em 01/01/1970 e teria precisão que caberia em 32 bits, por isso fazendo a conta de quantos segundos cabem aí (pouco mais de 2 bilhões, já que ainda tem o sinal), a data limite que pode chegar é 19 de janeiro de 2038, bem no começo do dia.

Como as pessoas usam certos recursos sem saber para que eles servem um monte de software está *bugado*, quase todas não sabem disto e agora o problema é muito mais grave que o *bug* do milênio, porque mesmo tendo solução fácil ele continua se proliferando, agora temos, talvez, milhares de vezes mais sistemas rodando que no fim do século passado, e que maioria já tinha nascido sem o problema da virada do século. É trágico, mas é o estado atual da nossa área onde as pessoas brincam de programar.

Não pode manipular data/hora com qualquer coisa que trabalhe com o *timestamp* padrão, como é o caso da [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

Tem também o problema do [Y10K](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_10,000_problem), entre [outros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_formatting_and_storage_bugs).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).