# Problema do Ano 2038

Tags: data, timestamp, unix, posix

**O que é o problema do ano 2038?**

- É semelhante ao bug do milénio?
- Já existem soluções para evitar a ruptura de informação?

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100231/112052

Comment: É o novo fim dos tempos (literalmente), escrito pelos programadores de 32-Bits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema ocorre por causa da forma que muitos sistemas escolheram para contar o tempo. Vários sistemas/linguagens/APIs atualmente usam [Unix timestamps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), que é a quantidade de tempo decorrida a partir de um instante predefinido.

O instante predefinido como o início (ou o "instante zero") é conhecido como [*Unix Epoch*](https://codeofmatt.com/please-dont-call-it-epoch-time/), e seu valor é 1 de janeiro de 1970, à meia-noite, em [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) (`1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`). E os timestamps são valores que definem quanto tempo se passou desde o instante zero.

Muitos sistemas guardam esse valor em [inteiros de 32 bits com sinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations), representando a quantidade de segundos que se passaram desde o *Unix Epoch*. O maior valor que este tipo pode guardar é [2.147.483.647](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2,147,483,647#In_computing) (pouco mais de dois bilhões). E 2.147.483.647 segundos depois do *Unix Epoch* equivale a `2038-01-19T03:14:07Z` (19 de janeiro de 2038, às 03:14:07, em UTC).

Um segundo depois disso, o próximo valor seria 2.147.483.648, mas como esse valor ultrapassa o máximo que um inteiro de 32 bits com sinal suporta, ocorre um [*overflow*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46789884) e seu valor passa a ser um número negativo. Mais precisamente, -2.147.483.648, o que equivale a cerca de 2 bilhões de segundos **antes** do *Unix Epoch*, que equivale a `1901-12-13T20:45:52Z` (13 de dezembro de **1901**, às 20:45:52, em UTC).

---

Qualquer aplicação/sistema/linguagem/API que use inteiros de 32 bits com sinal para armazenar os timestamps está sujeita a esse problema. Mas se outros tipos forem usados, o problema ocorre em uma data diferente.

Se o sistema usa inteiros de 32 bits sem sinal, o maior valor possível passa a ser 4.294.967.294, então nesse caso só ocorrerá um problema similar em fevereiro de 2106.

Muitas linguagens e sistemas já usam timestamps de 64 bits, por exemplo, o que garante um intervalo bem maior (mas ainda sim as futuras gerações poderão ter o bug do [ano 292.277.026.596](https://ximalas.info/2015/03/10/when-does-the-64-bit-unix-time_t-really-end/), a menos que a arquitetura de computadores - e a contagem do tempo, entre outros fatores - mude drasticamente até lá).

De qualquer forma, as soluções variam muito de um sistema para outro, pois depende do quão dependente cada aplicação é dos tipos que guardam os valores dos timestamps, e de como ela manipula tais valores.

Por exemplo, se uma aplicação usa inteiros de 32 bits com sinal e lida com datas anteriores a 1970 (ou seja, datas cujo timestamp é um número negativo), você não poderia mudar para inteiros de 32 bits sem sinal (que só suportam valores positivos).

Muitos sistemas podem ser recompilados/alterados para usar tipos de 64 bits, mas dependendo do caso, pode não ser possível para não causar problemas de retrocompatibilidade. Cada caso é um caso e [não há uma solução universal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem#Possible_solutions).

Comment: Agora percebo porque é que o antigo programador colocou todas as datas em string. brain 100

Answer (score 2):

O que é o bug:
O bug trata-se do término da sequencia numérica de 32 bits que é usada para contar o tempo a partir do meio dia de 1 de janeiro de 1970 adotado principalmente pela linguagem C e derivados. O número máximo é de 2147483647 e irá encerrar dia 19/01/2038, a partir daí, ele passa a usar esse número de forma negativa e deve decrescer até o 0. Então quem tem sistemas que utilizam datas futuras podem ter problemas com isso.

Para resolver, uma alternativa é mudar a forma como a data é controlade de 32 bits para 64 bits, o que dá aí alguns muitos muitos e muitos anos de sobrevida.

Em resumo é isso, mas sinceramente não acredito que seja algo mirabolante, talvez mais um pânico desnecessário como foi o Bug do Milênio. Até aonde me lembro, nenhuma bomba nuclear foi lançada por conta disso hehehe.

Se der uma vasculhada, tem bastante material já sobre.

Eu tenho pesquisado sobre, pois meu sistema usa data futura por conta de longos financiamentos, mas não estou obtendo muitas dificuldades não.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Na verdade a contagem é feita a partir de *meia-noite* do dia 1/1/1970, em UTC: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time - claro que esse mesmo instante poderia ser meio-dia em alguma parte do mundo, dependendo do fuso horário, mas geralmente usa-se o UTC como referência para tal :-)

Comment: Bem lembrado! :)

Answer (score -1):

**O que é**
Esse possível problema surgiu a conhecimento popular a partir da música "Gangnam Style", nesse ano, os processadores de 32-bit podem parar de funcionar, pois não conseguirão mais contar o tempo, no caso da música, ela ficou tão famosa que quase atingiu o valor máximo em visualizações, e a partir disso esse fenômeno se tornou famoso.

Em 2038, às 3 horas, 14 minutos e 5 segundos de 19 de março, os computadores que estiverem usando sistemas de 32-bit não conseguirão lidar com a mudança de data, pois terão atingido seu limite máximo de contagem.

**O que tem que ser feito?**
Sistemas que usam processadores de 32-bit irão parar de funcionar ou ser trocados nos próximos 24 anos.
Esperemos todos que seja tempo suficiente para planejarem as mudanças de infraestrutura.

Comment: Na verdade o bug Y2038 é conhecido há muito tempo (bem antes do youtube existir), e o caso do Gangnam Style não tinha a ver exatamente com a data, e sim com o contador de visualizações (já que o video estava prestes a estourar o valor máximo que 32 bits suportam). Apesar de ter relação com a mesma coisa (o número máximo que 32 bits suporta), é incorreto afirmar que o problema do ano 2038 surgiu a partir do Gangnam Style

Comment: Considerei Implícito esses fatos, mas corrigi.

Comment: Outro ponto (e desculpe por eu ser tão pedante) é que o horário limite é 03:14 em [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). Mas nesse mesmo instante, dependendo do fuso horário, poderá ser um horário e dia diferentes (por exemplo, na Califórnia esse mesmo instante será 19:14 do dia 18). De qualquer forma, o problema ocorrerá em 2038 para todos :-)

Comment: Ah, e a data correta é 19 de janeiro (e não março) de 2038, às 03:14:07 (7 segundos, não 5), em UTC :-)

Comment: Ainda, sistemas e processadores 32 bits ou menos podem funcionar perfeitamente bem, desde que usem as estruturas de dados corretamente. Não tem nenhum problema um processador de 8 bits guardar datas muito maiores que 2038 e o problema é de programação e não de processamento.